# Magento Add Instructions to Purchase Order Method on Onepage Checkout

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

Magento 1.9.1 allows for payment instructions for Bank Transfer and Cash on Delivery, however, there isn't an instructions option for Purchase Order.  I'd like to have the same box type below the Purchase Order Number field when the user selects Purchase Order on the checkout.  How can I add Instructions in the following places:

- Admin Configuration (Purchase Order)
- One Page Checkout Payment Type: Purchase Order
- Order Review - Payment Method
- Receipt / Invoice Page

**Purchase Order (No Instructions)**
[image: Purchase Order 1]

**Bank Transfer (Instructions)**
[image: Bank Transfer 1]

**Bank Transfer (Payment Method Instructions)**
[image: Bank Transfer 2]

**Admin Configuration**
[image: Configuration]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ultimately solved this by going to `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/payment/form/purchaseorder.phtml` and edidted the source code here.

**From this:**

```
<ul class="form-list" id="payment_form_<?php echo $this->getMethodCode() ?>" style="display:none;">
    <li>
        <label for="po_number" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Purchase Order Number') ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" id="po_number" name="payment[po_number]" title="<?php echo $this->__('Purchase Order Number') ?>" class="input-text required-entry" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getInfoData('po_number')) ?>" />
        </div>    
    </li>
</ul>
```

**To this:**

```
<ul class="form-list checkout-agreements" id="payment_form_<?php echo $this->getMethodCode() ?>" style="display:none;">
    <li>
        <label for="po_number" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Purchase Order Number') ?></label>
        <div class="input-box">
            <input type="text" id="po_number" name="payment[po_number]" title="<?php echo $this->__('Purchase Order Number') ?>" class="input-text required-entry" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getInfoData('po_number')) ?>" />
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="<?php echo $this->getMethodCode() ?>-instructions-content agreement-content"><?php echo $this->__('your text here') ?>
        </div>
    </li>    
</ul>
```

Make sure to add `checkout-agreements` to the ul class.

Comment: Thank you, I needed something similar as I deal with mostly B2B (Business to Business) and we take a lot of purchase orders.  Great solution.  Something like this would make a great module or extension on GitHub.